# Cypress How to handle erors

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm testing a lot of things but some of them are not too important(like caption text fail)I want to add optional parameter (if its wrong thats okay continue testing)
I used to work with Katalon Studio, it has Change failure options(stop,fail,continue) Can I make it with Cypress for my test cases.
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u58k9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can't have optional tests in Cypress. There are good reasons for it if you read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikkel mentioned already Cypress doesn't like optional testing. There is a way how you could do that by using an if-statement as explained in this question: [In Cypress, is there a way to avoid a failure depending on a daily message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211144/in-cypress-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-a-failure-depending-on-a-daily-message/58213247#58213247)

But to do that for every test you optionally want to test can make a big pile up of your code. So if you don't care if it succeeds or fails, just don't test it.

Another way you can try to be more resilient is by cutting up the tests further more. But you have to make sure that the scenarios don't rely on each other otherwise they will still fail.